# How do I get the Splattercannon in Nuka-World?

Tags: fallout-4

I looked on the wiki and it said that I should get the Splattercannon through a quest that I have already done, but I still don't have it. I looked everywhere trying to find it, as I thought that there might be a way to get it that I cant figure out. Did I do something wrong? Is there someone I need to talk to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wikia page on the Splattercannon](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Splattercannon), you can buy it from [Aaron Corbett](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Aaron_Corbett) in the Nuka-Town market. It doesn't look like it's a quest reward at any point.

Answer (score 1):

The Splattercannon is a quest reward from Mason,but you have to pass a speech check. That's the only way to get that gun..the Problem Solving lover is basically the same gun and can be purchased from the weapon vendor in the market.

Comment: This is somewhat incorrect. The only way to get the **Splattercannon** is buying one, as stated in my answer. Your answer refers to the **Problem Solver**. This is a different gun with a different skin and mods than the Splattercannon, but with the same prefixes.